# Ion-select does not show selected option when value is an object type

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

**I am binding an object to the value property of select-option.**

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Choose</ion-label>
    <ion-select [value]="{key:'abc',value:'ABC'}">
      <ion-select-option value="{key:'abc',value:'ABC'}">ABC</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="{key:'pqr',value:'PQR'}">PQR</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="{key:'xyz',value:'XYZ'}">XYZ</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

**When popup opens it does not show the selected value.**

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPn2D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your data bindings are failing because the value property in `ion-select-option` holds a string, while the value property of `ion-select` holds an object.

**You need to bind the value property of ion-select-option.**

```
<ion-select-option [value]="{key:'abc',value:'ABC'}">ABC</ion-select-option>
```

I would recommend that you should not use the objects as value of `ion-select-option`.

Since, there is key & value in your object, you should make a more clear code. Keep the key part in value attribute of `ion-select-option`.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Choose</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="myKey">
      <ion-select-option value="abc">ABC</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="pqr">PQR</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="xyz">XYZ</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

In your component, declare a variable myKey and assign a value to it.

```
myKey='abc';
```

This is an example of 2-way data binding in angular. Read more here: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/template-driven/#_two_way_data_binding